# Access 2013 - One to Many relationship: Show all values on "One" side and only select values on "Many" side

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've got two tables - `tblSalaryBand` and `tblSalaryBandYear` linked by `tblSalaryBand.ID = tblSalaryBandYear.SalaryBandID`. Within `tblSalaryBandYear` I have values for BandMax and BandMin, and then a ReviewYearID. So for each Salary Band I can have a Max and a Min for each year.

What I would like to do is have a list of all Salary Bands and the Max and Min for the selected year. However there may not yet be a values for the Salary Band for that year in the `tblSalaryBandYear`.

I've got a continuous form setup which I can get to show all Salary Bands even if they don't have a value in `tblSalaryBandYear` using an left join:

```
SELECT tblSalaryBand.BandName, tblSalaryBandYear.BandMax, tblSalaryBandYear.BandMin, tblSalaryBand.ID AS SalaryBandID
FROM tblSalaryBand LEFT JOIN tblSalaryBandYear ON tblSalaryBand.ID = tblSalaryBandYear.SalaryBandID;
```

But when I try to filter them down by ReviewYearID they don't show at all if no value exists in `tblSalaryBandYear`.

```
SELECT tblSalaryBand.BandName, tblSalaryBandYear.BandMax, tblSalaryBandYear.BandMin, tblSalaryBand.ID AS SalaryBandID
FROM tblSalaryBand LEFT JOIN tblSalaryBandYear ON tblSalaryBand.ID = tblSalaryBandYear.SalaryBandID
WHERE (((tblSalaryBandYear.ReviewYearID)=[Forms]![frmHome]![SelectedYear]));
```

Is there a way to have all Salary Bands show and then only show values for BandMin and Max from the selected review year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the where clause effectively eliminates the rows without any matching ReviewYearID (and makes the join behave like an inner join instead of a left outer join).

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  tblSalaryBand.BandName, tblSalaryBandYear.BandMax, 
  tblSalaryBandYear.BandMin, tblSalaryBand.ID AS SalaryBandID
FROM tblSalaryBand 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tblSalaryBandYear 
    WHERE ReviewYearID = [Forms]![frmHome]![SelectedYear]
) AS SBY ON tblSalaryBand.ID = SBY.SalaryBandID
```

Comment: So trying out the first option - Access doesn't seem to like having [Forms]![frmHome]![SelectedYear] in the join. Gives me an error saying it isn't supported.

The second option works, but I don't think it'll pull the correct records in all situations. If I select a year that has no records for any salary bands I'm only getting bands showing that have no value for any year. They aren't the current year but they are Null.

Comment: @icouper Oh, I wasn't aware that Access doesn't support the construct in the first query. I see the issue with the second query - let me think a minute

Comment: I'll do some searching to see if there's a way for the former to work in Access, but if you have any other ideas that would be awesome.

Comment: @icouper I've updated my answer - I think it should work now.

Comment: Awesome that looks like it worked. Any suggestions on where I can read up on that kind of join/subquery and how it works? I have a feeling I'll be needing that info.

Comment: @icouper Any good SQL/database book should cover the use of derived tables in my opinion, but I can't recommend any particular.

Comment: No problem. I'll take a look around for some resources on derived tables. Thanks again!